# Livepatch on 22.04 can't start says platform is 21.04

Tags: 22.04, patch

When trying to activate livepatch with:

```
sudo ua attach <token>
```

I get:

```
error executing status: livepatchd error: The platform Ubuntu 21.04 is not supported. exiting.
```

Though my platform is 22.04

```
lsb_release -a                               
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
```

Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

Comment: Is this system release-upgraded from 21.04 or some other non-LTS release? Or is this a clean install of 22.04?

Comment: It is upgraded from 21.04 to 22.04.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the file:
`/etc/lsb-release` was out of date and pointed out to release 20.04 (though the system thought it was 21.04) so I updated the info on it.

After `sudo snap remove canonical-livepatch` and `sudo snap install canonical-livepatch` I was able to connect to live patch with `sudo ua attach <token>` that you can acquire from https://ubuntu.com/advantage with your UbuntuOne login.